# How do I use Docke image blazemeter/taurus in Gitlab CI/CD script?

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, taurus

> I want to run Blazemeter Taurus in Gitlab CI/CD script
> When I run the pipleine I get following error message

```
Usage: bzt [options] [configs] [-aliases]
bzt: error: no such option: -c
```

> The script look like this

```
preformence_acceptance-test:
  image: blazemeter/taurus
  stage: acceptance-test
  script:
    - docker run -it --rm -v /performancetests:/bzt-configs blazemeter/taurus *.yml
```

> The Report from the Gitlab CI/CD runner looks like

```
Running with gitlab-runner 14.1.0-rc1 (e9489c8a)
  on docker-auto-scale ed2dce3a
Resolving secrets
00:00
Preparing the "docker+machine" executor
01:15
Using Docker executor with image blazemeter/taurus ...
Pulling docker image blazemeter/taurus ...
Using docker image sha256:fda4318ae51a2c0a42be56cb60a9608d3c341d64af2892708770c2ccb316ecc8 for blazemeter/taurus with digest blazemeter/taurus@sha256:490650f22656be8dfcf97b558ce77b9b6d63db8fedf76b76dc39a09091496873 ...
Preparing environment
00:01
Running on runner-ed2dce3a-project-28600761-concurrent-0 via runner-ed2dce3a-srm-1628256776-93452fb3...
Getting source from Git repository
00:04
$ eval "$CI_PRE_CLONE_SCRIPT"
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/steinKo/ci-cd-template/.git/
Created fresh repository.
Checking out d25af824 as 4-implement-testing-of-scalability...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Downloading artifacts
00:02
Downloading artifacts for backend-assemble-artefact (1483449685)...
Downloading artifacts from coordinator... ok        id=1483449685 responseStatus=200 OK token=rpZ_XgVo
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:03
Using docker image sha256:fda4318ae51a2c0a42be56cb60a9608d3c341d64af2892708770c2ccb316ecc8 for blazemeter/taurus with digest blazemeter/taurus@sha256:490650f22656be8dfcf97b558ce77b9b6d63db8fedf76b76dc39a09091496873 ...
Usage: bzt [options] [configs] [-aliases]
bzt: error: no such option: -c
Cleaning up file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 2
```

> How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

preformence_acceptance-test:
stage: acceptance-test
image:
name: blazemeter/taurus
entrypoint: [""]
script:
- cd performancetests
- "bzt *.yml"